# FullCalendar and visibleRange

Tags: fullcalendar

I need a calendar but for a fix month, i need the month of August ONLY and I'm trying to do that with the property `visibleRange` without success.
This is my code. Calendar works, but it keeps showing me the current month.

```
<script src="{{asset('fullcalendar/packages/core/main.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('fullcalendar/packages/daygrid/main.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('fullcalendar/packages/timegrid/main.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('fullcalendar/packages/list/main.js')}}"></script>
<script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                plugins: ['dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list'],
                defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
                visibleRange: {
                   start: '2020-08-01',
                   end: '2020-08-31'
                },
                locale: {
                    code: "es",
                    week: {
                        dow: 1,
                        doy: 4 
                    },
                    allDayHtml: "Todo<br/>el día",
                    eventLimitText: "más",
                    noEventsMessage: "No hay eventos para mostrar"
                },
                header: {
                    left: 'prev, next',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth',
                },
                weekNumbers: false,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

                events: []
            });
            calendar.render();
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by without success? any error, which version you use

Comment: You want to show only one specific August? Set `defaultDate` as 1st August 2020, and don't show the forward/back (i.e. "next"/"prev") buttons in your header.  And set `showNonCurrentDates` false to disable any days from July/Sept which might show up. (Or, maybe, if you require next/prev buttons to be available for when the user changes to week or day view, you can keep those buttons, but  instead use `validRange` to ensure they cannot navigate outside of August.)

Comment: thanks, i solved by using the `goto()` method after setting the instance, but i'll try your approach!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call after instantiation the method `gotoDate`

```js
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    // your options
});
calendar.render();
calendar.gotoDate('2020-08-01')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `timeGrid` instead of `dayGridMonth` as defaultview

```
defaultView: 'timeGrid',
visibleRange: {
   start: '2020-08-10',
   end: '2020-08-12'
},
```

Comment: thanks @Nasser but what if I want to show a month view in the month of august (since the whole congress is in August) and I'm in february?